# In Snowflake, what is the purpose of ALTER USER xxx SET RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP = '' instead of letting snowflake compute it itself?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [ALTER USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user) allow,  according to the documentation, to set the `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP` (fingerprint). But what is the purpose of doing that? If you set `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY` the `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP` will be automatically computed from the value of the public key.

I can't find any example on the documentation where they will actually use `ALTER USER xxx SET RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP = 'xxx'`, so what is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really use `ALTER USER xxx SET RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP = 'xxx'`, even if the [ALTER USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user) documentation list `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP` and `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_2_FP` in the `objectProperties` as one of the properties that you can set, it's not really the case.

If you try to write / set that property it will fail with `invalid property 'rsa_public_key_fp' for 'USER'`:

```sql
ALTER USER jsmith set rsa_public_key_fp = 'SHA256:agaRbT6c3Vv5/YVw2yVrMVucHws7ZYRrxx4dpGeX9gI=';
invalid property 'rsa_public_key_fp' for 'USER'
```

The `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP` is really read-only and meant to be read with `DESCRIBE USER jsmith` after setting `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY`.